# How to handle the the onClick events on CheckBox in react js

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

> I have an array called **initialList** the array contains three items these items have their own **checkboxes**, when I check on any of the items I want to push them into the **list** Array and at the same time remove them from the **initialList array**, I don't know what to write in the **clickHandler function** and how to render the **list** array

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function CheckBox3() {
    const initialList = [{id: 1, name:'jim'},{id: 2, name: 'joe'},{id: 3, name: 'beth'}]
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    const clickhandler = () => {
       
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <ol>
                {initialList.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>{item.name}
                    <input type="checkbox" onClick={clickhandler} />
                    </li>))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CheckBox3
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning Neel.

if checkbox - there is only 2 possible values - boolean false/true.
So it's good idea to use **negation** here.

then U use **onChange** instead **onClick**:

<input type="checkbox" onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}/>

---

I suggest to hold the actual checkbox value in state:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState()
```

Also if You have x checkboxes - there is need also for holding, which id of checkbox is in which state.
Or - just add **checked** parameter to your initialList object.

```
[
    {id:1 checked: false}
    {id:2 checked: true}
]
```

And also - for identifier You can add i to your map function - and in check function - reverse the value of i - id :

```
            {initialList.map((item, i) => (
                <li key={item.id}>{item.name}
                <input type="checkbox" onClick={(i) =>check(i)} />
                </li>))}
```

Comment: I think the right way is to either `onChange={handleChecked}` or `onChange={event => handleChecked(event)}`

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for what you are trying to achieve.

What I did was I check if the checkbox is checked and if it's then push it to the `list` array and check if it item exists in the `initialList` and if it does too it should filter it out.

```
function CheckBox3() {

    const [initialList, setIinitialList] = useState([{id: 1, name:'jim'},{id: 2, name: 'joe'},{id: 3, name: 'beth'}])
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    const clickHandler = (e, item) => {

        if (e.target.checked) {
            setList(prevState => [
                ...prevState,
                item
            ])
            const newInitialList = initialList.filter((list, index) => list.id !== item.id);
            setIinitialList(newInitialList)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // Perform whatever you want to do when list changes here
        console.log(list);

    }, [list])

    return (
        <div>
            <ol>
                    {initialList.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e, item)} />
                    </li>))}
            </ol>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: when i click on checkbox named "jim" nothing adds to the list array=[], when i click the checkbox named "joe" then jim is added to the list array=["jim"], and when i click on beth the list array = ["jim", "joe"] beth is never added

Comment: You can simply use useEffect to check once the listArray changes to get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to keep the list in the componente state, add/update the checked property every time an item is clicked:

```
function CheckBox3() {
   const initialList = [{id: 1, name:'jim'},{id: 2, name: 'joe'},{id: 3, name: 'beth'}]
   const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);
    

   const clickhandler = ({target}) => {
       const {checked, id} = target;
       setList(prev => {
         const clickedItem = prev.find(item => item.id.toString() === id);
         clickedItem["checked"] = checked;
         return [...prev];
       });
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <ol>
                {initialList.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>{item.name}
                    <input type="checkbox" id={item.id} onClick={clickhandler} />
                    </li>))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then you can filter the selected items:

```
const selected = list.filter(item => item.checked);
```